# Run shell script until one line left on the file

Tags: linux, shell-script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "file to split?"
read file
f=0
until ! [ -s $file ];
do
        grep -n "<text" $file > titles.txt
        lines=$(cat titles.txt| sed -n 2'p' | sed -r 's/^([0-9]*).*/\1/g')
        f=$((f+1))
        substrac="$(($lines-1))"
        head -$substrac $file > $f
        sed -i '1,'$substrac'd' $file
        echo "file \"$f\" generated"
done
```

This script runs until the `$file` is empty, but I need it to run until there is either 1 line left on the file "titles.txt" or one occurrence of "`<text`" in $file.

I have tried:

```
while :
do
        count=$(grep "<text" $file | wc -l)
if [ $count > 1 ]
then
```

and:

```
while :
count=$(cat titles.txt | wc -l);
do
until [ $count -eq 1 ]; do
```

But I can not make the script to stop at that point, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can not find what...

Comment: Quote all of your variables.

Comment: use `-gt` instead of `>`

Comment: ^^^ As George says, remember, if you are in POSIX sh. Further, you could run `sh -x ./script` to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is a well-formed XML file and you want to extract the `<text>` nodes into separate files, then the following does that using XMLStarlet:

```
#!/bin/sh

infile="$1"

xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//text/@id' -nl "$infile" |
while read id; do
    xmlstarlet sel -t --var id="'$id'" -v '//text[@id = $id]' "$infile" >"$id.txt"
done
```

Given the pathname of a file such as the following on the command line,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <text id="cade2296-1">
The first text, called "cade2296-1".
</text>
  <text id="cafr3062-1">
The second text, called "cafr3062-1".
</text>
</root>
```

... this would create the two files, `cade2296-1.txt` and `cafr3062-1.txt`, in the current directory, with the content of the two `<text>` tags in the original file.

The filenames are taken from the `id` attribute of the `<text>` tags.  These `id` values are first extracted from the XML, and then used in the loop to extract the relevant tag values.

Changing `-v` to `-c` in the XMLStarlet invocation inside the loop would give you a *copy* of the `<text>` XML tags, and not just the data in the tag.

Comment: Fair enough, good solution, but I couldn't apply it because I have found some texts containing 2 </text> tags, so at that point results broke down.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, thanks to @George Vasiliou I culd make it work, now the script goes this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "file to split?"
read file

# This variable is to name resulting files
f=0

while :
do
    # Count how many occurrences of "<text" are in the file to split
    count=$(grep "<text" "$file" | wc -l)
if [ "$count" -gt 1 ]
then

    # Send the occurrences of "<text" with their line number to the titles.txt file
    grep -n "<text" "$file" > titles.txt

    # From the second line of titles get the line number
    lines=$(cat titles.txt| sed -n 2'p' | sed -r 's/^([0-9]*).*/\1/g')

    # Every time the script is run the resulting file gets the next number as name      
    f=$((f+1))

    # From the line number obtained at the second line substract 1
    substrac="$(($lines-1))"

    # Create a new file taking the amount of lines indicated by the substraction from the splitting file
    head -"$substrac" "$file" > "$f"

    # Delete the lines corresponding to the newly created file from the splitting file to start the process over
    sed -i '1,'"$substrac"'d' "$file"
    echo "file \"$f\" generated"
else
    echo "process finished!"
    exit 1;
fi
done
```

**Explanation:** I have a huge text file with this format:

```
  <text id="cade2296-1">
  many
  undetermined
  lines
  ...
 </text>

 The same schema repeteated undetermined times

  <text id="cafr3062-1">
  many
  undetermined
  lines
  ...
 </text>
```

And what I need is every schema in a different file.

Comment: If you could explain what the script is supposed to be doing, someone may be able to clean it up a bit. It looks horribly inefficient as it stands, and I can't quite make out whether it actually runs all those `sed` invocations _for each line of the file_...

Comment: @Kusalananda Ok, I've added explanations to the answer post!

Comment: Is the file a well-formed XML file?

Comment: @Kusalananda I can not completely assure that, but mostly yes, it is not only one file I'm working with, but many, and those are generated by different people, I mean each file generated by different people.